# Problems with debug mode and isolate gutter-position on Susy Grid system

Tags: css, sass, grid, susy

I'm trying to see the debug mode on Susy to know how is the grid working and figure out if we have problems, but when I add this to my susy-config it's showing no debug mode.

I'm using version 2.2.12. This is my code on _variables.scss:

```
$susy: (
  column-width: 45px,
  columns: 12,
  container-position: center,
  container: auto,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  gutter-position: after,
  gutters: 18px / 45px,
  math: static,
  output: isolate,
  debug: (
    image: show,
    color: rgba($debugg-color, .2),
    output: background,
  )
);

$susy-desktop: (
  column-width: 67px,
  columns: 12,
  container-position: center,
  container: auto,
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  gutter-position: after,
  gutters: 30px / 67px,
  math: static,
  output: isolate,
  debug: (
    image: show,
    color: rgba($debugg-color, .2),
    output: background,
  )
);
```

[Image of the full Grid without the debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkv9M.png) and the buttons with a `margin-top: -100%` added because we use `output: isolate`.

*We want the first button to `span(2 at 8)` and second one `span(2 at 10)`).*

The grid overlay is a Chrome Plugin (not the Susy debug mode) that doesn't work as needed as you can see.

I'm using this Sass in our buttons:

```
.btn--full {
  @include span(2 at 8);
  margin-bottom: 28px;

  &.btn--ghost-darkgrey {
    @include span(2 at 10);
  }
}
```

[This is the representation of the buttons without `gutter-position: isolate` and `math: fluid, output: float`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAKg.png)

**So we have this problems:**

- We can's see Susy's debug mode.
- If we use isolate mode the buttons break

Comment: The "debug" mode should apply a background image to any use of the `container` mixin. Is that mixin used anywhere? If so, is there any chance you are overriding the generated background-image with one of your own? Also: I'm not sure I understand yet how `isolate` is breaking the buttons. Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: We need to have two Susy static layouts.

One for small breakpoints (`$tablet: 46.125em; - 738px`) and another to bigger ones (`$desktop: 70.875em; - 1134px`) want to archive this https://codepen.io/IgnaciodeNuevo/pen/XgPgVG

So we want when the layout gets bigger than `$desktop: 70.875em` to chanche to $susy-desktop

Comment: To give you more info here is the output http://imgur.com/a/r5rIj

As you can see the code in the DevTools the `.w01-wrapper .btn--full ` gets a `margin-right: -100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like debug mode is working properly in your CodePen sample. I forked that, and [added a sample `$desktop` breakpoint](https://codepen.io/mirisuzanne/pen/4ec079bb64cc577d3c883ca1ae4bc4fd/).

Isolation is a technique developed by John Albin Wilkins, using negative right margins [to help avoid sub-pixel rounding errors](https://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret). Isolation removes elements from the natural flow, so it works best if you isolate all the elements in a given context. You could solve that several ways: isolating all the paragraphs so they don't overlap, or using `last` on the button paragraph (rather than isolation) to float the buttons right.

Without knowing your markup limitations, or the desired look, it's hard to be more specific.

Let me know if I missed something.